# How to set ticks between ticks in TeecChart

Tags: c#, teechart

I am currently using a valid license of `teechart`, and I am doing a `utilization graph`(just like the process one in winxp).

My issue is I want to add ticks between `seconds` and I'm not sure how to.

So for example I want to be able to see on the bottom axes : `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` (Theses are seconds) And between seconds I want to see ticks (10 ticks per seconds)

> 0 "0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9" 10

While being able to set the ticks I don't want to see the actual number.

So i want to set a list of X,Y between 0 a 1 sec.

Is it do able?

Comment: I have fixed my problem by adding 10 Y between each seconds and setting text to " ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is doable. You only need use the property of Axes MinorTicksCount that determines the number of Axis minor ticks between major ticks. Please see next code line to see as you do to achieve it:

```
 tChart1.Axes.Bottom.MinorTickCount = 10;
```

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Sandra

Comment: Thanks, I didnt see the property at first, how can I access the minorTicks? I know to access the major I do :  TChart.Series[0][0].Y

Comment: I want to be able to set all the points from it. So in between 0 and 1. I want 9 settable points =) . Kind of confusing I know.

Comment: @Jonathan to get MinorTicks without text on them set axis Increment to 1, for example:
          tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = 1;
          tChart1.Axes.Bottom.MinorTickCount = 9;